How to connect python with cloud sql mysql
I'm trying to connect my code in Python with a mysql instance that is in Cloud SQL, I created a user for myself and I'm using the public i available in the instance interface as host, but I'm getting the following error:
ERROR:google.cloud.sql.connector.instance:['project:location:instance']: An error occurred while performing refresh. Scheduling another refresh attempt immediately
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 126, in refresh
    self._retrieve_info(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 99, in _retrieve_info
    info = _metadata.get_service_account_info(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 318, in get_service_account_info
    return get(request, path, params={"recursive": "true"})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 243, in get
    raise exceptions.TransportError(
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7d0011838310>)


MySQLInterfaceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    326         try:
--> 327             self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
    328             self._cmysql.converter_str_fallback = self._converter_str_fallback

MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_public_ip' (110)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    330                 self.converter.str_fallback = self._converter_str_fallback
    331         except MySQLInterfaceError as err:
--> 332             raise get_mysql_exception(
    333                 msg=err.msg, errno=err.errno, sqlstate=err.sqlstate
    334             ) from err

DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_public_ip' (110)



Here is my code:
#### Establish Connetion ####

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='my.user', password='my_password', host='public_ip_address', 
                              database='plus_data')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

#### Connetion Established ####

#### Execute query ####

query1 = ("select 1")
cursor.execute(query1)

I've already tried creating another user, I've already tried using a private IP

Hello, did you tried adding the public IP address in networking tab of MYSQL. Note:
The public IP address is basically IP address from which you are trying to access the DB.

TCP error 110 means that the network connection attempt timed out. This is not a python problem and most likely not a mysql issue either. You need to get your GCP network configuration in order.

I think you can use sqlalchemy to create that connection.
Check up this question: Can SQLAlchemy be used with Google Cloud SQL?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For Public IP connections to Cloud SQL you have two options.

(RECOMMENDED) Use a Cloud SQL Connector (Cloud SQL Python Connector, or Cloud SQL Proxy) to get a secure mTLS/SSL connection to your instance by default.
Use Authorized Networks: Add the IP address of the environment/client that you are attempting to establish the connection from to the list of Authorized Networks.

By default you can not just connect to your Public IP address from anywhere which is why you are running into the issue you are seeing. You must establish connectivity with your instance via one of the two methods listed above in order to successfully connect.
